# Run Kix Script C#

Tags: c#

In order to run a kix script you have to put a myScript.kix file in that same directory as kix32.exe then from cmd go to that directory and

```
Kix32 myScript
```

Then your kix script will run.

I want to do this in .net programatically. I am not sure the plumbing on how to accomplish this I have this so far but this will only run Kix32.exe where do I put info about myScript?

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = Kix32;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the script in the `Arguments` property of `StartInfo`:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\path\to\kix32.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "myScript";
```

The combination of the two would look like `kix32.exe myScript` on the command line.

Comment: This outputs an error ERROR : FUNCTION without ENDFUNCTION! but kix32.exe myScript works in command line

Comment: How can i be certain the cmd line kix32.exe myScript is running from the proper directory

Comment: It's very likely that you could specify full paths if you want, with `.FileName = @"C:\full\path\to\kix32.exe"` and `.Arguments = @"C:\full\path\to\myScript"`. If that latter path has spaces in it, you will need add more quotes: `.Arguments = "\"C:\\full\\path\\to\\myScript\""`